# How to change exposed filter select box style in views

Tags: 7, views

i have on exposed filter in views.it in defatult drupal select box style. how to change it like attached screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fancyselect](https://www.drupal.org/project/fancyselect) module.

> Fancy select is a jQuery plug-in developed by Octopus Creative.
>
> This module loads fancySelect jQuery plug-in, which converts simple HTML select DOM elements with a specified CSS class into a stylish select box. You may configure DOM CSS from settings form.